# Invalid OAuth2 token coming from WebAPI2 template

Tags: oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2, jwt

I'm working through a WebAPI2 template that comes with VS2013. I'm using local accounts, and eventually Google via OAuth2. This template seems to implement OAuth2 even for local accounts.

I was able to perform a login request and receive a token back. I wanted to decode this JWT to get a look at what was inside, but it doesn't appear to be a valid token format. What kind of token is this?

```
{
    "access_token": "Dj10K27SEp_79osDdKRIOSCuMRSvyw_Hh6SF0tGbELyHG7gfdE7rbcWFQMZI4Z0DaUBSYTODBKoVzecsfHIJTSVqPn7RqfVRlsx3d3diP8fEVt_QSFPT-WMJVCFVVrXyeUflOy_Qllj2I2voW7yNArUEBQ6WMlyohAlCYS4efqHCEjJyguHHVXEzIt2zGZPrlTWHyfoeCp569mFrN_WKL6cPgOWREF4z5fYdgeQco3OKgDpkL3WsczQT7hEoSwxiLl7iq_MKlyAGLKAzb4_qpAfwyBglFE9xzl91j-LC9ceFMS_eJ3YQ4TWhPqY7DGvbWLhWYYQON67tcHxO0KiJE8ZE4fqszhyGzCRKJGF5KqIBcicx2DGpYJhXm3QULsuHfp8SjLB2JO18x9hFVumrJ2CpBE4F3WIWW0aBadUd-cQxj1PBOn3Xyl1hFiSkdluEsHz-RNWiAKlGMRmyInrTcz1Yqr02wOC0XPTLM_7O9TI",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "expires_in": 1209599,
    "userName": "Test@Test.com",
    ".issued": "Wed, 01 Apr 2015 19:27:18 GMT",
    ".expires": "Wed, 15 Apr 2015 19:27:18 GMT"
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a non-standard JSON "container" token that seems to include a standard OAuth 2.0 access token. There's a hint in there that says who the user is but unless you can verify the source of the token, the integrity of that value cannot be guaranteed. IOW: it is a custom token that can only be interpreted by custom code.

Comment: Is this the standard for ASP.Net? How can I decode it?

Comment: it is already decoded; you should be able to use the `access_token` against an API

Comment: What I mean is - I can take a JWT and use a utility to see the plaintext inside. Is there a similar utility for this type of token?

Comment: the access token is not a JWT, the structure in which is embedded is a JWT and it is already decoded